# Foreman exits with code 0?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sunspot, foreman

I installed the Foreman gem, in order to start Sunspot each time I run my app:

**Procfile:**

```
search: bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:start
```

This is the output:

```
alex@alex-K43U:~/rails/inkleak$ foreman start
08:05:09 search.1 | started with pid 5278
08:05:35 search.1 | java version "1.6.0_24"
08:05:35 search.1 | OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.11.5) (6b24-1.11.5-0ubuntu1~11.10.1)
08:05:35 search.1 | OpenJDK Client VM (build 20.0-b12, mixed mode, sharing)
08:05:35 search.1 | Removing stale PID file at /home/alex/rails/inkleak/solr/pids/development/sunspot-solr-development.pid
08:05:35 search.1 | Successfully started Solr ...
08:05:35 search.1 | exited with code 0
08:05:35 system   | sending SIGTERM to all processes
SIGTERM received
```

What could be the problem?

(By the way, Sunspot runs just fine when I do `rake sunspot:solr:start`)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `sunspot:solr:start` task forks Solr into the background and immediately exits. That doesn't work well with Foreman, which assumes a long-running foreground process.

What you want here is `sunspot:solr:run` which will run Solr in the foreground, allowing Foreman to manage the process.

Alternately, if I may be so bold, you might also consider a [cloud hosted Solr search](https://websolr.com/) such as my own humble [websolr.com](https://websolr.com).